# Is there a way to ignore saving the operations in Azure Mobile Sync on the local, mobile device?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

We have an application that is using Azure Mobile services for offline sync capabilities connecting to an external API. The database schema has to be extended with a new table for data that will only be used on the mobile side. So, that table doesn't need to be synced to the server side.

I am wondering if there is a way to use the same `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices` libraries as we do in other parts of the application (as all the data access layer is built on top of it), but making it either:

1. ignore persisting the changes to that new table entirely (we don't need to keep track of those) - ideal solution
2. OR purging the operations queue before every push/pull of the operations on that table - uglier, but acceptable

Documentation didn't specify use cases like this.

Basically, I'm looking for something like

```cs
_store.DefineTable<LocalEntity>(); 
await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(_store);

// when we use the table...
// ideally this would only save it to the local SQLite, and not to the operations queue
var table = _client.GetSyncTable<LocalEntity>();
await table.InsertAsync(instanceOfLocalEntity); 

// when we sync up
// alternatively, make this ignore the LocalEntity table or see if there's a way to purge
// pending operations
await Client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
```

We could set up a new `SQLiteConnection` within the app to handle this table separately, but that seems overkill. Any ideas?